# Finding Values that contain all in hashset

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a form that sends a parameter to the controller for a checklist of categories.  For my other queries, I send the form data:

```
public ActionResult Index(string[] category)
```

Put each on into a hashset:

```
if ((category != null) && (category.Count() > 0))
{
    foreach (var item in category)
    {
        categoryHashset.Add(item);
    }
}
```

I have used

```
categoryHashset.Contains(object.Category)
```

Type set up in the where statement.  That works great for most of my queries, since most tables have one category mapped to one group.  So one group may appear in a table many times, but be linked to many categories.  So I would then do:

```
var groupCount = studyGroup
.GroupBy(s => s.ID)
.Select(g => new { ID = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

foreach (var checkCount in groupCount) //check or filter as well
{
    if (checkCount.Count == category.Count())
    {
        otherHashset.Add(checkCount.ID.ToString());
    }
}
```

However, in this specific case, each category is in one column in the table, separated by a pipe (|).  If a user checks more than one category, I only want to pull back groups that have all those categories in the column.  So in other words, if I person checks "cat" and "dog", it should only pull back:

```
Group    Category
Star     cat|dog|bird
Night    cat|bird
Sky      cat|dog
```

Star and sky from the above table example.

How could I deal with the pipes and get the correct results back?

Comment: Your example of how other categories work doesn't seem to include `categoryHashset` or any `where` condition to filter `groupCount` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the `studyGroups` before grouping to fetch only the ones that their categories (Category split by a '|') contains all of `categoryHashSet` like this:

```
var groupCount = studyGroup
.Where(group => 
       categoryHashset.All(c => group.Category.Contains("|" + c + "|") 
                                ||
                                group.Category.StartsWith(c + "|")
                                ||
                                group.Category.EndsWith("|" + c)
                                ||
                                group.Category.Equals(c))
.GroupBy(s => s.ID)
.Select(g => new { ID = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Note that you cannot use `group.Category.Split()` since that is not supported in linq to entities even though that seems more logical in this case.

Comment: This is not working.  I believe is is still looking at it as (first item in hashset is dog, is the column dog|cat included), which it isn't.

Comment: @yondaimehokage Look at the edit of my answer. In the example `["dog","cat"]` it filters the groups that in their `Category` it either has the string `"|dog|"` or it starts with the string `"dog|"` or it ends with the string `"|dog"` and then the same for "cat". Isn't this what you requested in the example?

Comment: Yes.  But as I said, it is not working.  I selected only one category to test, and it is only returning groups that have a category of "cat" but not "cat|dog".

Comment: @yondaimehokage Not sure why though. If I search with `["cat"]` it gives me back groups with `Category`: `cat|dog|bird, cat|bird, cat|dog`. I edited the answer to also get groups that have exactly `cat` in their category so you might want to check the most recent one as well. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Yeah, I had already added that Equals part already too.  Not sure why it is so restricted.  Maybe it is the hashset being read wrong?

Comment: @yondaimehokage It might help if you only run the `Where()` function I added in `studyGroups` separately and omit the `GroupBy()` so you can see what groups are you filtering first. I am not sure why you checked this `checkCount.Count == category.Count()` because the count of groups grouped by id and the count of categories are totally unrelated, as far as I can understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142534/discussion-between-granit-and-yondaimehokage).